# TeamCity: Use Configuration Parameter in Custom build

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I was trying to set some parameters when running custom build.  "Param1" is set to "Release". "Param2" is set to "%Param1%". I expect Teamcity can resolve "Param2" as "Release". However I received an error "Param1 is not fully resolved".

Comment: It might help to understand the problem if you provide the screenshot of the way you run the custom build as well as where the error appears.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get this working by using `Custom run` dialog and providing parameters as the following:

[image: Setting parameters]

Both `param1` and `param2` are not defined in the configuration, only in `Custom run`

Here's the simple `Command line` runner that prints `%param2%`, and it actually prints `value` in the build

[image: Echoing param2]